Why a 16 amperes plug and cord have 6 amperes socket attached

The manufacturer says that this 16 amperes plug and cord has dual rated sockets in the board(16A/6A). Is this configuration safe for 6 ampere appliances?

If the manufacturer says it's rated for 6A plugs, what causes you to think it is not? If you don't trust the manufacturer I would not buy this product even if we agree with them.

are you expecting to be able to plug two 16 A appliances at the same time?

Is this device listed as approved by your national electrical regulatory body? In the US, that would be Underwriters Laboratory (usually) and it would have a UL™ mark on it. In the UK, it would have the British Kitemark on it. There are similar labs/marks in most countries of the world.

Additionally, there appear to be white marks on the device in the picture. Are you blanking out the manufacturer's name? You shouldn't do that here - knowing the brand/model might help someone look it up for you to help you better understand what you've got your hands on.

I just wanted to avoid undefined consequences. I may put the original picture after giving it a hard thought. The item is from a reputed manufacturer in India.


I may plug two 16 amp appliances, or one 16 amp and one 6 amp, taking wattage into consideration. 2. I do not know, if it is approved or not, but generally you cannot sell them, if not approved.  3. The appliances may or may not have fuses. Need to check and recall.


I checked some plugs by different reputed manufacturers, and they bear the ISI mark of the standards authority of India. A similar item from the above manufacturer, and also some local vendors, however do not have any approval mark. But the findings are not uniform,even some reputed Indian manufacturers do not have the ISI mark. Example Crompton Greaves.

Perhaps this is my cultural ignorance; could you please explain: "cord has dual rated sockets in the board(16A/6A)"? Current carrying capacity ratings of connectors and cords are as a rule single values based on resistive heating effects. You add "1. I may plug two 16 amp appliances, or one 16 amp and one 6 amp, taking wattage into consideration."  I rather doubt the cord is rated for 32 amps, perhaps one 16 amp device and one 6 amp device (=22A)?  As for taking wattage into consideration, it is proportional to current for most rating purposes; how would you "take it into consideration"?

It seems like a bad design or they expect people to be smart(usually causes death).  If the plug/wire is 16 amp rated then you can have two 6 amps or one 16 amp device plugged in.  Doing anything else will probably not be good.

@crip659 That's the same as any power strip. Take a typical US power strip that has a 15 amp plug, cord, and 8 15 amp outlets. Overload protection is provided by a circuit breaker or fuse. OP's equivalent is something like the Eaton PDUMH20, a 20 amp input PDU you can plug 15 or 20 amp plugs into.

The link to the item: https://www.amazon.in/MX-Extension-Outlet-Shutter-Retardant/dp/B0CVQCGXHB

Many thanks for all the comments. I decided it is probably best to avoid these kind of configurations.

India's dual rated sockets have the little snowman shape to allow 2 or more different plug geometries.  It's similar to the NEMA 5-20R in the USA which allows either the 5-15P or the 5-20P plugs.
That means a 16A power tap dual rated for 16A/6A can be used for any combination of those plug types, so long as the total current doesn't exceed 16A.  Plug type doesn't equal current.  You'll need to look at the equipment labels to find out how much current each one will draw.
